# Aligning two images in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align two images horizontally using CSS. In CSS, I have:

```
#poster1 {
background-image: url(audioMaster1.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0px 40px;
padding-top:595px;
}
#poster2 {
background-image: url(audioMaster2.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0px 0px;
padding-top:595px;
}
```

and in HTML, I have at the moment:

```
<div id="poster1"></div>
<div id="poster2"></div>
```

but, obviously, the images are below each other, which I do not want. I would like the images to be side by side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the `div` elements an explicit width; otherwise they will expand to fill all available horizontal width.

You will then need to `float` them or use `inline-block`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/42nBq/).

Comment: Could you explain a bit more alex? I do not think what you are saying solves my problem. My problem is that images are tiled vertically rather than horizontally.

Comment: @James Check the fiddle... is that what you want?

Comment: @james you'll need to give us some info about the images an what do you mean by tiling as you have `background-repeat: no-repeat;` btw Awesome name ;)

Comment: alex, that is precisely what I wanted, but now, I have some other trouble: the white spaces on either sides of my pictures are disproportionate. Is there a way to remedy this? Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some things, try this:

```
#poster1 {
background-image: url(audioMaster1.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0px 40px;
padding-top:595px;
float:left;
}
#poster2 {
background-image: url(audioMaster1.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0px 0px;
padding-top:595px;
float:left;
}
#wrapper{}
```

Notice the floats. You can also add width to specify how wide you want it.

It is also common to add a wrapper too.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="poster1">aa</div>
    <div id="poster2">bb</div
</div>
```

Comment: strimp.. your approach does not seem to work for me.. The images seem to dissapear when I add float:left to div elements.

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this:

```
CSS: #image1, #image2 {float:left; display:inline-block; background:#000; width:250px; height:250px; margin:5px;}

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="image1"><img src="1" /></div>
<div id="image2"><img src="2" /></div>
</div>
```

You should find you have two black boxes side by side, simply replace the background:#000 with your image URL so for instance it would be : background:url("audioMaster1.png") no-repeat 0px 40px;

You can then use the "Wrapper" to move both images around together. :)

That should do the job.

Comment: Hi magnum, I tried your suggestion, but, it still alligns the images vertically and not horizontally. What I done is used:    #poster3 {
      background-image: url(findoutmore.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: 285px 20px;
      padding-top:50px;
      overflow:hidden;
      width: 590px;
      float:left; <div id="poster3"></div><div id="poster3"></div> in my HTML .. It seems to work in Firefox.